# Need Between Range rows between using previous end_date and next start_date

Tags: sql, mysql, select, stored-procedures, dql

While working white Availability of Resources. I got struct here. Let me explain so expect to get some help here.

Considering a table Availability as below create script with sample records for better understanding.

```
CREATE TABLE availibility ( 
   id int NOT NULL,
   start_date date NOT NULL, 
   end_date date DEFAULT NULL, 
   status tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO availibility (id, start_date, end_date, status) VALUES (1,'2024-02-01', '2024-02-10', 1), (2,'2024-02-21','2024-02-29',1);
```

Now it returns result as below:

| ID | Start Date | End Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2024-02-21 | 2024-02-29 | 1 |

While my expectations is to return in between row as well. Sample below.

| ID | Start Date | End Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-10 | 1 |
| NULL | 2024-02-11 | 2024-02-20 | 0 |
| 2 | 2024-02-21 | 2024-02-29 | 1 |

Help will be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: the title has the logic - read up on lead , date_add and date_sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have change my answer

Of course! If you've modified the query so that the ID doesn't play a role anymore, and it's possible for a smaller ID to appear much later in the sequence, let's test it. Could you please provide the modified query or any specific changes you've made to it? Once I have that information, I'll be able to assist you further and test it accordingly.

```
(SELECT * FROM availibility order by start_date)
  UNION ALL
( WITH ranked_end_date AS (
    SELECT *,LEAD(start_date) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS next_start_date
    FROM availibility
)
SELECT NULL AS id, end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY , next_start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 0 AS status
FROM ranked_end_date
WHERE next_start_date is not null
AND DATEDIFF(next_start_date, end_date) > 1 )
ORDER BY start_date;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/5oi4khgB

Comment: yes, you can also use inner join

Comment: Appreciate for your reply, it works as given data only, But  In case i am adding another row as below, it won't work, I expect it return dummy data for all in between rows. I had provided sample test case only for understanding purpose.

INSERT INTO `availibility` (`id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `status`) VALUES ('4', '2024-03-08', '2024-03-10', '1');

Comment: @RushabhMadhu Then you can use ROW_NUMBER to create the contiguous set for the join - https://dbfiddle.uk/_FAALRkL

Comment: Thank you @user1191247 and Bernd Buffen for your quick help, it makes my day.

Comment: WITH availability AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_date ASC) AS rn FROM availibility
)
(SELECT * FROM availibility)
  UNION ALL
(select null AS id
    , a.end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS start_date
    , b.start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS end_date
    , 0 AS status
FROM availability a
INNER JOIN availability b ON b.rn = a.rn+1
WHERE DATEDIFF(b.start_date, a.end_date) > 1)
ORDER BY start_date;

Here is my final solution.

Comment: @Rushabh Madhu
 - i have change my answer without using the id field

Answer (score 0):

Another way is, using UNION:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  status
FROM availibility

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  NULL, 
  DATE_ADD(a1.end_date,INTERVAL 1 DAY),
  DATE_ADD(a2.start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY),
  0
FROM availibility a1 
INNER JOIN availibility a2 ON a2.id=2
WHERE a1.id=1
ORDER BY start_date
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/5xKLoV3F)

EDIT: Added the comment from @RushabhMadhu, in a readable format:

```
(SELECT * FROM availibility order by start_date) 
  UNION ALL 
( WITH ranked_end_date AS ( 
     SELECT *,LEAD(start_date) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS next_start_date 
     FROM availibility ) 
SELECT 
  NULL AS id, 
  end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY , 
  next_start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 
  0 AS status 
FROM ranked_end_date 
WHERE next_start_date is not null AND DATEDIFF(next_start_date, end_date) > 1 ) 
ORDER BY start_date
```

see: [DBFIDDLE2](https://dbfiddle.uk/1PLdLUwP)

Comment: i have checked but it seems above need some improvement as my request is also dynamic and may be it can have multiple rows which has some missing dates. but below is the perfect answer for my question.

(SELECT * FROM availibility order by start_date) UNION ALL ( WITH ranked_end_date AS ( SELECT *,LEAD(start_date) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS next_start_date FROM availibility ) SELECT NULL AS id, end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY , next_start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 0 AS status FROM ranked_end_date WHERE next_start_date is not null AND DATEDIFF(next_start_date, end_date) > 1 ) ORDER BY start_date

Comment: comment are pretty hard to read, when they contain code, so I added your statement to the answer.